# JMeter: Stoptest.sh/Shutdown.sh doesn't work from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am running some performance tests from Jenkins. I do have two Windows machines with JMeter and I can configure from Jenkins which one to use. Everything works as expected here.

My issue: I did create another job for Stop/Shutdown the tests in case something goes wrong and you have a big run time. Whenever I try to summon Stoptest.sh/Shutdown.sh on the Windows machine that run tests, nothing happens.

How can I stop tests remotely? It has anything to do with the listening port? Thank you.

PS: Tests are ran using PSExec from Jenkin's Windows slave so there is no active CMD window on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that `.sh` is extension for [Linux shell scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script), they cannot be executed by Windows command-line interpreter ([CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) or [Powershell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)) if you're running JMeter on Windows you need to go for [`shutdown.cmd`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_0/bin/shutdown.cmd) or [`stoptest.cmd`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_0/bin/stoptest.cmd) instead

There is also [AutoStop Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-autostop-listener-how-to-do-it-right) plugin which can be used for conditional stopping of JMeter test basing on various criteria, it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked. For some reason the port in jmeter.properties was set under 1000 and it did not listen to any. Setting it to 4445 solved the issue.